# Как сделать, чтобы при появлении боковой панели контент смещался?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется боковая панель, div блок с контентом, который появляется при выборе пункта "Buttons". Панель перекрывает содержимое данного пункта, как сделать чтоб при открытии контент сдвигался в бок?

```js
const menuBurger = document.querySelector(".burger-menu");
menuBurger.addEventListener("click", function() {
  menuBurger.classList.toggle('burger-menu_active');
});

document.querySelector('.burger-menu__nav').addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.tagName !== 'A') return;
  if (event.target.innerText.trim() === 'Buttons') {
    let div_btns = document.createElement('div');
    div_btns.className = 'btns';
    document.body.appendChild(div_btns);

    var h = document.createElement("H1");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Buttons");
    h.appendChild(t);
    div_btns.appendChild(h);

    let p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = "Choose color: ";
    div_btns.appendChild(p);

    let inpt = document.createElement("input");
    inpt.id = 'idColor';
    inpt.setAttribute("type", "color");
    div_btns.appendChild(inpt);

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      let btn = document.createElement("button");
      btn.className = "buttons";
      btn.innerHTML = "Click me :)";
      div_btns.appendChild(btn);
    }
  }
})

document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  const color = document.getElementById("idColor").value;
  if (!event.target.classList.contains("buttons")) {
    return;
  }

  if (event.target.style.backgroundColor) {
    event.target.style.removeProperty("background-color");
  } else {
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
});
```

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  height: 76px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 7px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

footer {
  background-color: #01003f;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  z-index: 2000;
  box-shadow: 0px -3px 7px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  margin: 0 20px 20px 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.burger-menu__button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  z-index: 30;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.burger-menu__button:hover .burger-menu__lines {
  filter: brightness(0.7);
}

.burger-menu__lines,
.burger-menu__lines::after,
.burger-menu__lines::before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.burger-menu__lines {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.burger-menu__lines::before {
  content: '';
  top: -10px;
}

.burger-menu__lines::after {
  content: '';
  top: 10px;
}

.burger-menu_active .burger-menu__button,
.burger-menu_active .burger-menu__lines {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.burger-menu_active .burger-menu__lines::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.burger-menu_active .burger-menu__lines::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.burger-menu__nav {
  padding-top: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 20;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
  overflow-y: auto;
  left: -100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.burger-menu_active .burger-menu__nav {
  left: 0;
}

.burger-menu__link {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.burger-menu__link:hover {
  filter: brightness(0.7);
}

.burger-menu__overlay {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 10;
}

.burger-menu_active .burger-menu__overlay {
  display: block;
}

[id="burger-menu__nav"]:checked~main>.btns {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(320px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(320px);
  transform: translateX(320px);
}

.buttons {
  background-color: #808080;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px 23px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
  margin: 5px;
}

.buttons:hover {
  box-shadow: 3px 9px 8px -1px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.45);
}

.buttons:active {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.btns {
  margin-left: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="burger-menu">
      <a href="#" class="burger-menu__button">
        <span class="burger-menu__lines"></span>
      </a>
      <nav class="burger-menu__nav" id="burger-menu__nav">
        <a href="#" class="burger-menu__link">Create table</a>
        <a href="#" class="burger-menu__link">Buttons</a>
        <a href="#" class="burger-menu__link">Sliders</a>
        <a href="#" class="burger-menu__link">Students table</a>
        <a href="#" class="burger-menu__link">Progress Bar(Promises)</a>
        <a href="#" class="burger-menu__link">Map</a>
        <a href="#" class="burger-menu__link">jQuery table</a>
        <a href="#" class="burger-menu__link">Mediator pattern</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <section></section>
  </main>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Это сложно, потому что блок с контентом "не знает" о том, что открылось меню. Лучш передвинуть меню так, чтоб не закрывало контент.
Например возможно такое решение: присвоить по клику класс основной секции (также как и с боковым меню)

```
const mainSection = document.querySelector("main"); // эта

menuBurger.addEventListener("click", function () {
  menuBurger.classList.toggle('burger-menu_active');

  mainSection.classList.toggle('active'); // эта
});
```

в стили добавить

```
main section {
  transition: .3s ease-in;
}

main.active section {
  padding-left: 25%;
}
```

Пример
https://codepen.io/maxkuku/pen/zYjbyQR

Comment: Видел подобное реализовано через transform: translateX(...px) в css, но там контент изначально находится на странице. Адаптировать под своё как-то не получилось

Comment: @wavy_ делают два блока рядом друг с другом но под input type="checkbox" при отмеченом состоянии смещаете второй блок с  анимашкой и всё